# Delphi with Bluetooth Low Energy: Discover Devices

Tags: android, delphi, bluetooth

I'm starting an application with Bluetooth Low Energy, developing for Android in Delphi 10.2 Tokyo and Windows 10.

I created a new project containing a TButton and a TBluetoothLE object in a TForm. The TButton OnClick event contains only this code:

```
BluetoothLE1.Enabled: = True;
BluetoothLE1.DiscoverDevices(2000);
```

In my first tests there were two problems:

**Problem 1**) When running app (with F9) and executing `BluetoothLE1.DiscoverDevices(2000);` no BLE device is found if it does not run the above OnClick twice (but there is a BLE device running and available near by me which I can find using another app). Even if I change the TimeOut value (plus or minus), no device is found if `BluetoothLE1.DiscoverDevices` is run only once.

**Problem 2**) When app is closed (after running with F9 and executing DiscoverDevices), `Invalid Pointer Operation` occurs. This error also occurs with Embarcadero BluetoothLE examples. There is no error if running app with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>.

Is there a solution to these problems? How?

Answer (score 2):

Taking everything into consideration that has been said on this thread regarding BluetoothLE and Windows 10 etc...

I'll take some time explaining the issue to outline what is causing this seeming problem, which actually has a very straightforward solution. I couldn't find anything online about this, so I'll explain it in detail for someone else who might be struggling to get this to work on their Windows 10+ PC. (Note: I did not test this on Mac, iOS or Android, so if you encounter the same issue by simply calling the method "DiscoverDevices" directly, try implementing the below solution)

I had the same issue until I looked at the "TBluetoothLE" component code. There is an essential step to ensure to call in your code before calling the method "DiscoverDevices". Strangely and frustratingly enough, it is not outlined in the Delphi Help Documentation, or even in books like "Fearless Cross-Platform Development with Delphi" where the topics surrounding Bluetooth and BluetoohtLE are also discussed in great depth.

After stepping through the code of the unit "System.Bluetooth.Components", I discovered that the reason the method "DiscoverDevices" seems to be failing, is that the primary instance of "TBluetoothLEManager" is never created, and returns "nil" when calling the method "DiscoverDevices". Note that the method "DiscoverDevices" is a function returning a boolean value, so the correct implementation of calling this method is not by calling it directly without testing the returned result. Again, something that is not outlined in the help documentation anywhere. You should call this method in the following manner:

```
    if not(BluetoothLE.DiscoverDevices) then
      ShowMessage('Discover Devices Failed!');
```

At least now you'll know whether the method succeeded or failed after calling it. If the result yields true, it will then fire the following 2-primary events:

```
    BluetoothLEDiscoverLEDevice
    BluetoothLEEndDiscoverDevices
```

Now, let's look at the code for the method "DiscoverDevices" to see what's happening and why is this method failing when calling it:

```
    function TBluetoothLE.DiscoverDevices(ATimeout: Integer): Boolean;
    begin
      if (FManager <> nil) and SupportsGattClient then
        Result := FManager.StartDiscovery(ATimeout)
      else
        Result := False;
    end;
```

As soon as the "DiscoverDevices" method is called, as is the instructions in the books and Delphi Help Documentation, the instance of "FManager" (TBluetoothLEManager) is nil, which by condition yields "false". The only part in the code where an instance of "FManager" is actually created, is in the "Setup" method" of this same unit:

```
    procedure TBluetoothLE.Setup;
    begin
      FManager := TBluetoothLEManager.CreateInstance; //<-- "FManager" instance created
      FManager.ForceRefreshCachedDevices := FForceRefreshCachedDevices;
      FManager.EnableBluetooth;
      FManager.OnDiscoveryEnd := DoInternalDiscoveryEnd;
      FManager.OnDiscoverLeDevice := DoInternalDiscoverLEDevice;
    end;
```

The "Setup" method is only called when the "Enabled" property is invoked by setting it to "True" so that the code fires to create an instance of "FManager". Thus, in order to create an instance of "FManager" so that the "DiscoverDevices" method returns "true", you need to enable the component "TBluetoothLE" BEFORE calling the method "DiscoverDevices":

```
    BluetoothLE.Enabled := True;
```

This will cause the code to execute to create an instance of "FManager".

```
    procedure TBluetoothLE.SetEnabled(AEnable: Boolean);
    begin
      if not (csDesigning in ComponentState) then
        TThread.Synchronize(nil, procedure
          begin
            FEnabled := AEnable;
            if FEnabled then
            begin
              if FManager = nil then
                Setup; //<-- Method invoked to create instance of "FManager"
             end else
               begin
                 if FManager <> nil then
                 begin
                   CancelDiscovery;
                   FManager.Free;
                   FManager := nil;
                 end;
                 if FServer <> nil then
                 begin
                   FServer.Free;
                   FServer := nil;
                 end;
               end;
          end)
            else
              FEnabled := AEnable;
    end;
```

Finally, the correct way of implementing the code is to ensure the "FManager" instance is created so that the necessary events are fired after the method "DiscoverDevices" is successfully called.

Simply do the following:

```
    BluetoothLE.Enabled := True; //<--- Without this, no instance of "FManager" exists
    if not(BluetoothLE.DiscoverDevices) then
      ShowMessage('Discover Devices Failed!');
```

Hope this helps anyone else struggling to get the LE Bluetooth Devices to be detected.

Answer (score 0):

You can find only paired BLE devices when run your application on Windows platform. There are lot of bug in Delphi Bluetooth implementation. I do not know about Android part, but for Windows you need other solution than default Delphi.

Comment: Yes, I had previously noticed that only paired devices can be found in Windows. Do you know any better libraries for Bluetooth LE in Delphi? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, but this appears as advertising and I afraid I cab be banned for that. Look for Bluetooth Framework.

Comment: I meant: is there a cross platform library for use of Bluetooth Low Energy on Android and Windows? From what I've seen, this framework is not cross platform.

Comment: I afraid no, there is no cross platform library for Delphi that supports BLE communication.